# Most efficient way to keep the user logged in

Tags: node.js, session, session-cookies

I'm building a school project in Node.JS, thats the first time that I am developing an app in Node.js. And I would like to know an efficient way to keep the users logged in on my app.

I'm storing the e-mail and password in sessions, but I read that this is a really bad idea because the hackers can access to that information.

Can someone give me a better idea to implement?

My code

```
     var sess;
     app.use(session({
       secret: "test",
       resave: true,
       saveUninitialized: false,
       rolling: true,
       cookie: {
         httpOnly: false,
         secure: false,
         maxAge: 6000000
       }
     }));
     //Post Login
     app.post('/', function(req, res) {
       logIn(req, res, req.body.login, req.body.password);
     });
     app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
       sess = req.session;
       if (!sess.email && !sess.password) {
         console.log("nope");
       } else {
         logIn(req, res, sess.email, sess.password);
       }
     });

     function logIn(req, res, login, password, session) { 
       ...
       sess.email = login;
       sess.password = password;
       ...
     }
```

Thank you

Comment: You're right. Password shouldn't be stored in session, it should be encrypted aswell with something like bcrypt. You could have a look at passport.js, a middleware that handles quite a lot authentication scenarios. Something to get you started, hope it helps: https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLillGF-RfqbbqvbObyE7CldS5-trkefnB

Comment: Thank you, I will watch this tutorial.